# How to read partially a Data object

Tags: swift, nsdate

The recent change in Swift 4 provides the simple way to initialize a byte array with your Data object. The result gets you an `[UInt8]` with the whole data stored into it.

```
let array = [UInt8](data)
```

I can't find the solution to load the same Data object only partially using an offset and a length. Is it possible without slicing the whole array or should I switch to InputStream?

Comment: Just use a `Range` applied to the `Data` object and convert the result to `[UInt8]`. `Data` conforms to `Sequence`. Very easy.

Comment: You mean like that: `let array = [UInt8](data[start..<end])` ?

Comment: You can also use `Data` method `subData` and pass a range like this `data.subdata(in: offset..<offset.advanced(by: length))`

Comment: Note that `Data` conforms to `RandomAccessCollection` so there is no need to convert your data slice to array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can slice a `Data` object with a subscript.

For example, you just want the 3rd to 5th index in the data, you would use

```
data[3..<6]
```

In your case, you would do

```
let array = [UInt8](data[lowerIndex..<upperIndex])
```

where `lowerIndex` and `upperIndex` are the indexes.

Comment: `data[3..<5]` would return only the 3rd and 4th bytes

Comment: @LeoDabus My bad, fixed

Comment: Note that Swift is a type inferred language. You dont need to specify the resulting type of your array `Array(data[lowerIndex..<upperIndex])`